# Zip 500 files into one output file

Tags: linux, unix

I have 500 files and I want to zip into one file output file.

Input files:

```
abc.pdf
afa.pdf
dgh.pdf
sdg.pdf
....so on
```

Desired output file should be:

```
abc.zip
```

Or

```
sdg.zip
```

Or any starting name of input file.

Answer (score 0):

just use the standard zip method for linux:

```
zip out.zip *.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your files are in the same directory, you could do this (run from the same directory):

```
zip abc.zip *.pdf
```